# What happened to my Pandora account?

Tags: microsoft, internet-explorer

Today is 28 August 2020.

My Pandora account (all my music) has somehow been deleted.  I can't even contact Pandora as their .com website gets me nowhere.

I admit it has been awhile since I have used it, but that shouldn't matter.